# How to get a parallel row value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out a way to get the parallel row value from Dataframe.

for Example :
i have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"TableName": ["Table1", "Table2"], "SQL": ["abc", "def"]})
```

Now i want to get the sql column value by using the TableName column values

if i put Table1 then output should be abc

i tried using this

```
selected_key = values["-list-"]
print(selected_key)
parallel_value = df1.loc[df1.columns("TableName") == selected_key]
```

Here selected_key does have `Table1`
This is a small peice of code out of the pack
the end output which i want would be

```
print(parallel_value)
output -- abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"TableName": ["Table1", "Table2"], "SQL": ["abc", "def"]})
```

For a single string query:

```py
selected = "Table1"
p = df[df["TableName"].eq(selected)]["SQL"]
print(p)

# 0    abc
# Name: SQL, dtype: object
```

Using a list of string as the query:

```py
selected = ["Table1"]
p = df[df["TableName"].isin(selected)]["SQL"]
print(p)

# 0    abc
# Name: SQL, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response 
I got an error stating "Lengths must be equal"

Comment: What is the type of `selected_key` is it a string or a Series?

Comment: it's a string I printed the value to be sure about the output it returned this  `['Table1']`

Comment: actually selected_key is more like a single selected string value from a list of strings

Comment: You should update your question with exactly what your variables are.

Comment: sure that's a small piece of code from the larger one
do you want me to paste the full code here ?

Comment: No, just the bits that are relevant to your example code. For example, what is the `values` variable? It looks like it could be a dataframe or a dict?

Comment: Actually that a PySimpleGUI Variable and rest of the code is of PySimpleGUI 
`values["-list-"] ` that's more or less the same as ` x = 'Table1'` 
a little more context to it as i mentioned earlier as well selected_value will be a single value from a list of string value like in dataframe we had table name's `table1, table2, ... ` . User will be selecting a single value from listbox and value is going to be stored in selected_key whatever he/she selected and to store it .values() function is used here

Comment: Your first error suggests that what you are getting from `values["-list-"]` is not a single string value, it is likely a single element list. If that's the case using `.isin` instead of `.eq` will work in my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

set the index and the fetch the value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"TableName": ["Table1", "Table2"], "SQL": ["abc", "def"]})
df = df.set_index('TableName') # set index
result = df.loc['Table1'].values # fetch value
```

Comment: instead of just the parallel value it's displaying the table header and the searched value as well, 
can you help me out with just the value nothing else

Comment: by mistake it pressed the edit button and i didn't made any changes to the answer as well